# pytorch not tokenizing data

Tags: python, pytorch, tokenize

I have this code:

```py
import json
import os
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
from tokenizers import Tokenizer
from tokenizers import Tokenizer, models, pre_tokenizers, decoders, trainers

def train_tokenizer_on_concode_data(train_data, vocab_size=30000):
    # Initialize a BPE tokenizer
    tokenizer = Tokenizer(models.BPE())

    # Set the pre-tokenizer and decoder
    tokenizer.pre_tokenizer = pre_tokenizers.ByteLevel(add_prefix_space=True)
    tokenizer.decoder = decoders.ByteLevel()

    # Set the trainer and train the tokenizer
    trainer = trainers.BpeTrainer(vocab_size=vocab_size, special_tokens=["<s>", "<pad>", "</s>", "<unk>"])
    tokenizer.train_from_iterator(all_texts(train_data), trainer)

    return tokenizer

def all_texts(data):
    for item in data:
        nl = item.get('nl', '')
        code = item.get('code', '')
        yield nl
        yield code

# Load the CONCODE dataset
def load_concode_dataset(file_path):
    data = []
    with open(file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        for i, line in enumerate(file):
            try:
                item = json.loads(line)
                if 'nl' in item and 'code' in item:
                    data.append(item)
            except KeyError:
                print(f"Error at line {i}: {line}")
    return data

# Tokenize the dataset
def tokenize_concode_dataset(data, tokenizer):
    tokenized_data = []
    for item in data:
        if 'nl' in item and 'code' in item:
            tokenized_nl = tokenizer.encode(item['nl'])
            tokenized_code = tokenizer.encode(item['code'])
            tokenized_data.append((tokenized_nl, tokenized_code))
    print(f"Tokenized {len(tokenized_data)} examples")
    return tokenized_data

train_file_path = './data1/'  # Replace with the correct path
train_file = "./data1/python_train_0.jsonl"
train_data = load_concode_dataset(train_file)

print(f"Loaded {len(train_data)} examples from {train_file_path}")

vocab_size = 30000
tokenizer = train_tokenizer_on_concode_data(train_data, vocab_size)

print(f"Trained tokenizer with {len(train_data)} examples")

# Save the tokenizer
tokenizer.save("concode_tokenizer.json")

# Tokenize the dataset
tokenized_data = tokenize_concode_dataset(train_data, tokenizer)
print(f"Tokenized {len(tokenized_data)} examples")

if len(tokenized_data) >= 5:
    for i in range(5):
        print(tokenized_data[i])
else:
    print(f"tokenized_data has only {len(tokenized_data)} elements.")


# Load the tokenizer
tokenizer = Tokenizer.from_file("concode_tokenizer.json")
print("Loaded tokenizer")
# Create a dataset and dataloader for the tokenized data
class ConcodeDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, tokenized_data):
        self.tokenized_data = tokenized_data

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.tokenized_data)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return self.tokenized_data[idx]

# Create a dataset and dataloader for the tokenized data
dataset = ConcodeDataset(tokenized_data)
print(f"Created dataset with {len(dataset)} examples")
dataloader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=32, shuffle=True, num_workers=1)
print(f"Created dataloader with {len(dataloader)} batches")



# Save the tokenizer
tokenizer.save("concode_tokenizer.json")


# Load the tokenizer
tokenizer = Tokenizer.from_file("concode_tokenizer.json")
tokenized_data = tokenize_concode_dataset(train_data, tokenizer)
SOS_IDX = tokenizer.token_to_id('<s>')


class Encoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, num_layers):
        super(Encoder, self).__init__()
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.num_layers = num_layers

        self.embedding = nn.Embedding(input_size, hidden_size)
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(hidden_size, hidden_size, num_layers, batch_first=True)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.embedding(x)
        outputs, (hidden, cell) = self.lstm(x)
        return hidden, cell


class Decoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, output_size, hidden_size, num_layers):
        super(Decoder, self).__init__()
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.num_layers = num_layers

        self.embedding = nn.Embedding(output_size, hidden_size)
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(hidden_size, hidden_size, num_layers, batch_first=True)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(hidden_size, output_size)

    def forward(self, x, hidden, cell):
        x = x.unsqueeze(1)
        x = self.embedding(x)
        outputs, (hidden, cell) = self.lstm(x, (hidden, cell))
        predictions = self.fc(outputs.squeeze(1))
        return predictions, hidden, cell

class EncoderDecoderModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, encoder, decoder):
        super(EncoderDecoderModel, self).__init__()
        self.encoder = encoder
        self.decoder = decoder

    def forward(self, src, trg):
        # Get the encoder outputs and hidden state
        encoder_outputs, hidden = self.encoder(src)

        # Initialize the decoder input
        decoder_input = torch.tensor([[SOS_IDX]*trg.shape[1]])

        # Move everything to device
        device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
        encoder_outputs = encoder_outputs.to(device)
        hidden = hidden.to(device)
        decoder_input = decoder_input.to(device)

        # Initialize the decoder outputs tensor
        decoder_outputs = torch.zeros(trg.shape[0], trg.shape[1], self.decoder.output_dim).to(device)

        # Decode one step at a time
        for t in range(trg.shape[0]):
            output, hidden = self.decoder(decoder_input, hidden, encoder_outputs)
            decoder_outputs[t] = output
            decoder_input = trg[t].unsqueeze(0)

        return decoder_outputs

# Use the Seq2SeqModel class and update it with appropriate arguments for encoder and decoder
input_size = vocab_size
hidden_size = 256
output_size = vocab_size
num_layers = 1

encoder = Encoder(input_size, hidden_size, num_layers)
decoder = Decoder(output_size, hidden_size, num_layers)
model = EncoderDecoderModel(encoder, decoder)

# Train and save the model
def train_and_save_model(model, dataloader, num_epochs=1):
    device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
    model.to(device)

    criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
    optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)

    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        running_loss = 0.0

        for i, data in enumerate(dataloader, 0):
            nl_tokens, code_tokens = data
            nl_tokens = nl_tokens.to(device)
            code_tokens = code_tokens.to(device)

            optimizer.zero_grad()
            outputs = model(nl_tokens, code_tokens[:, :-1])
            loss = criterion(outputs.view(-1, outputs.size(-1)), code_tokens[:, 1:].view(-1))
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()

            running_loss += loss.item()

        print(f'Epoch {epoch + 1}, Loss: {running_loss / len(dataloader)}')

    print("Finished training")
    torch.save(model.state_dict(), 'trained_model.pth')

train_and_save_model(model, dataloader, num_epochs=1)
```

and it gives this error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_4252\67801769.py in 
     95 dataset = ConcodeDataset(tokenized_data)
     96 print(f"Created dataset with {len(dataset)} examples")
---> 97 dataloader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=32, shuffle=True, num_workers=1)
     98 print(f"Created dataloader with {len(dataloader)} batches")
     99 

c:\Users\vigop\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py in __init__(self, dataset, batch_size, shuffle, sampler, batch_sampler, num_workers, collate_fn, pin_memory, drop_last, timeout, worker_init_fn, multiprocessing_context, generator, prefetch_factor, persistent_workers, pin_memory_device)
    349             else:  # map-style
    350                 if shuffle:
--> 351                     sampler = RandomSampler(dataset, generator=generator)  # type: ignore[arg-type]
    352                 else:
    353                     sampler = SequentialSampler(dataset)  # type: ignore[arg-type]

c:\Users\vigop\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\sampler.py in __init__(self, data_source, replacement, num_samples, generator)
    105 
    106         if not isinstance(self.num_samples, int) or self.num_samples <= 0:
--> 107             raise ValueError("num_samples should be a positive integer "
    108                              "value, but got num_samples={}".format(self.num_samples))
    109 

ValueError: num_samples should be a positive integer value, but got num_samples=0
```

I did realise that I get this output:

```
Loaded 0 examples from ./data1/
Trained tokenizer with 0 examples
Tokenized 0 examples
Tokenized 0 examples
tokenized_data has only 0 elements.
Loaded tokenizer
Created dataset with 0 examples
```

also in the file where the jsonl file is, there's only one file. I am not sure if that could be a problem.

I tried modifying this:

```py
train_file_path = './data1/'  # Replace with the correct path
train_file = "./data1/python_train_0.jsonl"
train_data = load_concode_dataset(train_file)
```

What was happening is to the entire dataset, is just too big for now, so I wanted to start with only one file.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example